# how to return requestCode from child activity to parent activity in default back button click

Tags: android

I am having using **onActivityResult** method in my `ParentActivity` and i call a `ChildActivity` from my `ParentActivity` in a `Button` click. In my `ChildActivity` when I click the default back button and when it goes to my `ParentActivity` , I am not getting my **requestCode** that i set in my `ChildActivity` in `onStop()` method by:

> setResult(2);

How can I return my `requestCode` from my `ChildActivity` to `ParentActivity` when I click back button.

Here is my code:

```
      //Parent activity
      protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
            Toast.makeText(this,resultCode+"", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            if(resultCode==2){
                finish();
            }
        }
    
    //Child activity
      protected void onStop() {
           setResult(2);
           super.onStop();
            }
 protected void onPause() {
           setResult(2);
           super.onStop();
            }
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use this code in your child activity

```
@Override
    public boolean onKeyDown(int keyCode, KeyEvent event) {
        if(keyCode == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_BACK){
            setResult(RESULT_OK);
            finish(); // If you have no further use for this activity or there is no dependency on this activity
                    return true;
        }
        return super.onKeyDown(keyCode, event);
    }
```

This piece of code will return result ok code from your child activity to parent activity

Now in your parent activity in

```
@Override
    protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
        switch (requestCode) {
        case 2:
            if(resultCode == -1){
                // Here you write your code which you have to write on result receive
            }
            break;

        default:
            break;
        }
        super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
    }
```

Let me know if this helps you

Answer (score 0):

It is better to override onBackPressed() than to override onKeyDown()

Comment: its true to use onBackPressed method as its define specifically to back button key